# Why the method app.UseSwaggerUI(...) is not found?

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-3.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I want to add swagger on a new web application created with .NET Core 3.1. I receive an error on the following line:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
});
```

> 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSwaggerUI' and no accessible extension method 'UseSwaggerUI' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

even though I have installed Swagger as in [the MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

This is the content of swagger package that came from NuGet:

[image]

I have the following usings:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i see `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger` in your screenshot- but have you also installed `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi`?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann thanks a lot for the remark! I did not knew it was a separate nuget package and on MSDN it was not mentioned. If you post an answer, I will kindly accept it, as it solved my problem

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The NuGeT-package [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger/) only provides the JSON-endpoints of the documentation.

To actually have the UI as well, you must also install the corresponding package [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi/)

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi -Version 5.6.3
```

Comment: Actually i had to update to version 6.2.3 to get rid of that error.